# HTML indexing into JSON variable for NgModel

Tags: html, json, angular, angular-ngmodel

In all the component classes of each of page of my `Angular 2` form, I'm calling an API for retrieval of saved input values to be stored in a global variable in JSON format inside of a global service, if this global variable has not been filled in yet.

After retrieval and initializing the global variable with the JSON data from the API, I'd like to establish 2-way data binding using `NgModel` on each of my HTML pages with the corresponding values inside this global variable. However, I'm having trouble indexing properly into this global variable containing my JSON data. I'd like to bind my input value directly to the global variable, because upon saving of the form, I can simply call one service that would send this one global variable in the body of a POST call.

JSON Data stored in globalVariable:
How do I retrieve "value a", "value b", "value c" in the HTML?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "field 1" : "value 1",
      "page1" : {
             "field a" : "value a"
             "field b" : "value b"
       },
      "page2" : {
             "field c" : "value c"
       }
    }
   ]
}
```

page1.component.ts:

```
 constructor(..., public globalService: GlobalService:, @Inject(GlobalVariable) private globalVariable: any, ...) {}


ngOnInit() {
       if (Object.keys(this.globalService.globalVariable).length < 1) {
            this.globalService.getAPI().subscribe(
                data => this.globalService.globalVariable = data['data'],
                err => console.error(err),
                () => {

                    console.log(this.globalService.globalVariable[0]['page1']['field a']); //Prints 'value a' correctly!
             //In HTML:NgModel:  I can't index globalVariable[0]['page1']['field a']

                    //this._privateVariable = this.globalService.globalVariable;
               //In HTML:NgModel: I can't index _privateVariable[0]['page1']['field a']
                   //this._privateVariable = this.saveInformation.information[0]['page1']; 
                   //In HTML:NgModel: I can index _privateVariable['field a'] for ['value a'], but  //I don't want to manage many _privateVariables, each storing each page's input 
                   //values to be sent in POST request in save.

                }
            )
        }
    }
```

page1.component.html:

```
...

<div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="globalVariable[0]['page1']['field a']">
</div>
...
```

The above line outputs the following error to console:

```
angular2.dev.js:25644 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

There are mistake in your code while fetching data and using in the view (HTML). you have to use code like this :-

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="globalVariable.data[0].page1['field a']">
```

also

> PS: There is `space` between your name of key i.e `field a` so to access the value of JSON object key having space you have to use `bracket notation` of javascript.

see here working demo of your use case
<kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHqS8WbdYh3TUyxeqMCS?p=preview)</kbd>

see also

- https://medium.com/@prufrock123/js-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-797c4e34f01d#.ytvne8m86